# Problems with IPv4 identification field range

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, ip, ip-fragmentation

I used a UDP socket (IPv4) sending 64KB packet to an end-system. When I capture the packets of end-system using Wireshark, I found that the IP Identification field of the reassembled IP datagram range from `0x0000-0x7fff(0-32767)`, i.e, when the end-system received a datagram with ID `0x7fff`, the next datagram holds the id value of `0x0000` rather than `0x8000`.

It confused me a lot. Why not `0x0000-0xffff(0-65536)`?

My sender program is written with C# code, running on Windows7. Network interface card brand is Intel.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the identification field is a choice of the sender. It can be allocated in whatever fashion the sender likes. RFC 791 says this about it (emphasis added):

> The identification field is used to distinguish the fragments of one
>       datagram from those of another.  The originating protocol module of
>       an internet datagram sets the identification field to a value that
>       **must be unique for that source-destination pair and protocol for the
>       time the datagram will be active in the internet system.**  The
>       originating protocol module of a complete datagram sets the
>       more-fragments flag to zero and the fragment offset to zero.

So the sending system is free to restrict its `identification` values to 0 - 0x7fff as long as any one datagram is "unique ... for the time the datagram will be active."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way I can force the sending system to restrict the identification values to 0x0000-0xffff? I sent Udp packets in a high rate, so the error occurred mentioned in RFC4963：“If a sender wraps the ID field in less than the reassembly timeout, it becomes possible for fragments from different datagrams to be incorrectly spliced together ("mis-associated"), and delivered to the upper layer protocol” . Windows keep the fragments which are not reassembled in buffer for 60 s.If I can force the sender 
to use full range id value, this phenomenon will be reduced

Comment: I doubt there is any way to force that. If there is, it would be windows-specific. I would recommend you keep the size of datagrams small enough that they don't need to be fragmented. Consider that if you send a 64KB UDP datagram, it gets split into N smaller IP fragments (within the interface MTU -- usually 1500 bytes, so typically 44 fragments). If any one of those is dropped or corrupted, the entire UDP datagram will never be delivered to the receiver. If datagrams aren't fragmented, the content of the identification field is unimportant.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your advice!